# Discord Bot, Unable to get it to Mention user that used command

Tags: node.js

I am new to coding, and new to stackoverflow. I am attempting to have this.

if (command === 'gcc') {
msg.channel.send('`Welcome '<msg.author.name>' I see you have selected the name "<name> is this correct?`')
.then(function (msg){
msg.react(':15:818275907839721492')
msg.react(':14:818276739662479380')

output the message and call upon the Discord users name of the command to insert in place of '<msg.author.name>' and whatever they typed after it being inserted in place of

Any help is appreciated before my 9mo hits the nuke computer button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `msg.reply` which will automatically mention the user.

```js
msg.reply('Welcome ' + msg.author.name + '! I see you have selected the name...');
```

Or, you can do:

```js
msg.channel.send('Welcome <@' + msg.author.tag + '>! ...');
```

Comment: I appreciate it!, it's progress tho it returns a string of numbers for the Discord name instead of the discord name :(

Comment: Made an update. Is `msg.author.tag` any better?